# Export multiple data frames to multiple Excel worksheets

Tags: r

I'm trying to export multiple data frames into one excel file with multiple sheets.

This is the code I used:

```
setwd('C:/Users/Desktop/R')
library("readxl")
library("writexl")
AR <- read_excel("FEB_AR.xlsx",sheet="After sort")
library(plyr)
#Top 10
Top_10 = AR[order(AR$Amount, decreasing= T),]
Top_10 = Top_10[1:15,]
Top10 <- as.data.frame(Top_10)
#Top Over 60
Top_Over_60 = AR[order(AR$Total, decreasing= T),]
Top_Over_60 = Top_Over_60[1:15,]
TopOver60 <- as.data.frame(Top_Over_60)
sheets <- list("Top10" = sheet1, "TopOver60" = sheet2) 
write_xlsx(sheets, "C:/Users/Desktop/R")
```

This is the message I receive:

```
> sheets <- list("Top10" = sheet1, "TopOver60" = sheet2) 
Error: object 'sheet1' not found
> write_xlsx(sheets, "C:/Users/Adi.Koren/Desktop/R")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'sheets' not found
```

Also, I can't use the packages 'openxlsx' or 'xlsx' because they require a java update which I can't download (it's a work computer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
sheets <- list(sheet1 = Top10, sheet2 = Top_Over_60) 
writexl::write_xlsx(sheets, "result.xlsx")
```