# Export multiple workbook from R

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, tidyverse, readxl

Using below image to showcase what I am trying to do. So basically I have 2 workbook with 2 sheets at a location. I want to read them in R & perform two operation (Change 0 to NA & get average of each column) then export them back in the same manner to same location (2 workbook & 2 worksheet).

Details on Operation post import both workbook & worksheet are **a)** Convert all 0 to NA in all the sheets & **b)** then creating a average row at the end of each column. (Yellow highlighted in above image)

[image: Sample input to output requirement]

*In the above image **Yellow** highlighted in the output are the mean values of each column (post converting 0 to NA)*

I tried creating below code but the issue was I am not sure how to export multiple worksheet back to the same workbook basically in the order that I imported them.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

path <-  "C:/Users/tme/Desktop/"
file_name <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")

for (i in seq_along(file_name)){
  sheet_nm <- excel_sheets(file_name[i])
  for (j in seq_along(sheet_nm)){
    assign(x = paste0(file_name[i],"_",sheet_nm[j]), value = read_xlsx(path = file_name[i], sheet = sheet_nm[j],col_names=FALSE), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
}
```

Comment: As `readxl` can only read Excel files, you need to pick some other library for writing. https://readxl.tidyverse.org/index.html#other-relevant-packages lists and describes few options (openxlsx, writexl, tidyxl)

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798541/export-multiple-data-frames-to-multiple-excel-worksheets helps or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets